# Python how to read and write lists from files

Tags: python, list, file-io

I am pretty new to programming, I just recently finished the Python course in Codecademy, so I am sorry if this is a dumb question. I am working on a game so I can get more practice with what I already know. What I am trying to do is be able to read and write lists as well as mixed in variables in the .txt file. Here is what I have.

```
def read_file():
    global player_name, player_gender, player_lvl, player_gold, player_xp, player_items, strength, vitality, charisma, intellect, agility, player_hp, player_magicka, player_taunt, player_victory, player_fact, save_list, help_list
    save_file = open("savegame.txt", "r+")
    save_list = []
    for item in save_file:
        save_list.append(item)
    player_name = str(save_list[0])
    player_gender = str(save_list[1])
    player_lvl = int(save_list[2])
    player_gold = int(save_list[3])
    player_xp = int(save_list[4])
    player_items = [] #This is where I left it because I don't know how to read lists
    strength = int(save_list[6])
    vitality = int(save_list[7])
    intellect = int(save_list[8])
    charisma = int(save_list[9])
    agility = int(save_list[10])
    player_hp = int(save_list[11])
    player_magicka = int(save_list[12])
    player_taunt = str(save_list[13])
    player_victory = str(save_list[14])
    player_fact = player_name + str(save_list[15])
```

save_list is just the list I am extracting the variables and list from, I know it is probably not needed. On my fifth part of the list is where I want my other list to be, but I do not know how to get it out of its string form and turn it into a list. I know if this whole file was just one list I could iterate through it to make a list, but since I have other things around it, it's not that simple.

This is an example of what my save file(.txt) might look like. I need to figure out how to load the ["This part is supposed to be a list"] line as a list.

```
Mr May 
Male 
6
3340
1380
["This part is supposed to be a list"]
6
1
4
2
2
55
85
You suck!!!
I will never lose!!!
Mr May was tormented by potatoes as a child.
```

Also, it may be important to know my list will not stay the same size.

Any help is much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by this - "On my fifth part of the list is where I want my other list to be,"?

Comment: Please indent your code properly

Comment: Likely, the `player_items` is a comma-separated list of words?

Comment: It's better if you can provide us with an example input file and your expected output.

Comment: @shaktimaan: What I mean is on the fifth line down of when I assigning my variables(it is the line with 'player_items = []'), I want a list. But if I were to try to do a list, it would be read as a string because it is a text file.

Comment: @user3159253: My code is indented properly. My for loop is only supposed to have that one line of code in it, the rest of the code after that is not supposed to be in that loop. The loop simply appends items onto the list I am using for extraction.

Comment: @user3159253: And yes, it is going to be a comma separated list of words.

Comment: @bgamlath: Thank you for letting me know, I added an example of what my save file's contents might look like. That is the input. I am not sure why I need output, my output would basically look like that .txt save file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although this does not answer your original question I think it would be better if you used JSON rather than a plain-text file. Using JSON, you won't have to deal with difficulties like parsing a list from a text file. To do this create a json file (mine is called "player.json") that has a structure something like this:

> { "player": "GoofyBall", "level": 2000, "items": [ "dagger",  "sword",
>   "wand of doom" ] }

You can then parse the file for the desired attributes. Here I have reduced the json file to just a few attributes for demonstration purposes but you can add to it as required:

```
import json

json_data=open('player.json') #open the json file
data = json.load(json_data) # load the json data

# get the attributes you want
print "Player name:" + data['player'] 
print "Level: " + str(data['level']) 
print "Items" + str(data['items'])
```

I hope this helps your game.

Answer (score 2):

The piece of info that we need to set here is how the data in the file is formatted. For example we could put an element on each line:

```
1
2
3
```

and I would call this "line delimited". What I would suggest is storing and loading the data in the [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) format.

```
import json
json.dump([1,2,3,4], open("outfile2.json", "w"))
save_list = json.load(open("outfile.json"))
save_list
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

more documentation can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html?highlight=json#module-json).

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand quite what you mean. Should be clearer.
But from what I saw you are going to work manipulating data of different types.
It would be easier if you post the contents of the file: savegame.txt.

For example. If this file has the following line in 5 Content: Item 1, Item 2, Item 3.
You can get a new list using the split.

As follows:
player_items = save_list.[5].split (",")

The split works with a key character. In the example above I have used ','

This will return you to a new list: ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"]

Comment: I added my savegame.txt up there now. If I understand correctly, are you saying my line does not need to look like a list, but instead the items of the list without any brackets, quotes, or commas? And that split function would turn something like that into a list? That would be great if I am correct

Answer (score -2):

Something like

```
class Player:
    @classmethod
    def from_file(cls, fname):
        with open(fname) as inf:
            return cls(*(line.rstrip() for line in inf))

    def __init__(self, name, gender, health, hp, strength, charisma, intellect, agility, magicka, gold, xp, taunt, victory, items):
        self.name      = name
        self.gender    = gender
        self.health    = int(health)
        self.hp        = int(hp)
        self.strength  = int(strength)
        self.charisma  = int(charisma)
        self.intellect = int(intellect)
        self.agility   = int(agility)
        self.magicka   = int(magicka)
        self.gold      = int(gold)
        self.xp        = int(xp)
        self.taunt     = taunt
        self.victory   = victory
        self.items     = items.split(",")  # convert comma-delimited string to list

    def save_file(self, fname):
        with open(fname, "w") as outf:
            output = [
                self.name,
                self.gender,
                self.health,
                self.hp,
                self.strength,
                self.charisma,
                self.intellect,
                self.agility,
                self.magicka,
                self.gold,
                self.xp,
                self.taunt,
                self.victory,
                ",".join(self.items)    # convert list to comma-delimited string
            ]
            outf.write("\n".join(str(op) for op in output))

def main():
    char1 = Player.from_file("savegame.txt")
    # now do something with character!

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

A list can be converted to a string using `str.join`, as in `",".join(mylist)`. This assumes that the elements of mylist are already strings. The string can then be converted back to a list of string using `str.split()`, as in `mystr.split(",")`.

Using global variables is usually a bad idea because (a) it ties your function to a single set of variables - if you want to load a second character, you have to write another function; (b) it makes debugging harder because it is not obvious where data-changes are coming from; and (c) it clutters your global scope with lots of extraneous variables.

Making your function return a set of values or data structure is an improvement, in that it allows you to reuse code and reduces clutter; but it tends to lead to a whole bunch of functions that do various things to a data structure and often a bunch of similar-but-not-identical structures, with related almost-the-same functions and clutter and confusion.

The next step is make the various functions "belong to" their associated data structure - this is known as "object orientation" and is implemented in Python as a class. My code above creates a Player class which holds all related data for a single player and has member functions which can initialize a player, load one from file, or save back to file. I then have a main() function which demonstrates loading a player's data.

Several people have suggested using JSON as a storage type. This can be convenient, as it automatically converts strings and integers, lists and dictionaries; it is also easily edited by text editor or in other programs. On the other hand, it can be a bit of a trap, in that you end up dealing with a "bag of data" with associated clutter; it is unable to handle arbitrary data types ie classes.

Comment: Just dumping code as an answer with barely any explanation is not helpful to somebody who is new to the language.

Comment: I meant no offense. I do not require "hand-holding" myself but I think learning concessions and "teach-a-man-to-fish" type answers are sometimes lacking on SO. I am reverting my downvote because your revised answer does the above.

Comment: Thank you for your in-depth answer, I appreciate how you showed me different ways of doing things and the advantages/disadvantages to each of them. I will study this to try to figure out how to improve my programming, thanks